# Can iron oxide in well-point water be removed by electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Can iron oxide dissolved in well point water stored in a 1000l plastic tank be removed by using a 12V battery charger and simple electrodes? If so what material should the electrodes consist of?

Comment: No ! Iron oxide cannot be dissolved by electrolysis. It can only be dissolved by concentrated acids, like concentrated hydrochloric acid.

Answer (score 2):

If the plastic tank has access to air ,you do not need to do anything . Ferrous (
+2 ) is soluble in water . Ferric (+ 3) is not . So any ferric particles will settle out as oxides/hydroxides ,etc . Soluble ferrous iron will be oxidized by dissolved oxygen from air in hours to ferric , and settle out as oxides / hydroxides , etc. So ,with residence time to settle ,no agitation , and possible filtering , the iron in the water will be at a very low level. I accidently saw this chemistry in action once. I filled a swimming pool with private well water ( which I knew had some iron but did not treat for it) . This reqiured 12 or more hours . I turned off the pump at night , the next morning there was a couple inches of reddish jel-like layer on the bottom - the precipitated ferric iron. The standard swimming pool filter cleaned it out in about a day.

Comment: A jug with no cap does not constitute aeration. My experience with a ferrous salt with application of an air pump produced no results until the solution was acidic. This answer is also not in accord with any health agency recommendation, fails to provide any sources (one would think on matters of public health at least one reference, especially on a forum that enforces and disapproves of even promulgating accurate personal health advice ) and should be deleted. By the way, is there even an answer on the question of "electrodes" in this anecdotal story?  Otherwise, enjoyed reading this reply.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend following a refined version of this remedy suggested by a [state health department](https://www.health.state.mn.us/communities/environment/water/wells/waterquality/iron.html#:%7E:text=Aeration%20(injecting%20air)%20or%20chemical,will%20quickly%20plug%20the%20system), addressing iron in well water, to quote:

> Aeration (injecting air) or chemical oxidation (usually adding chlorine in the form of calcium or sodium hypochlorite) followed by filtration are options if iron levels are more than 10 mg/L. Sediment filter, carbon filter, or water softeners can remove small amounts of iron, but the iron will quickly plug the system.

My refinement on the aeration technique is to couple it with water electrolysis (liberating hydrogen and oxygen) employing carbon electrodes. And yes, the carbon electrode will breakdown, but it can be filtered out and the elemental carbon may [further absorb toxins](https://www.carbonblocktech.com/the-science-behind-activated-carbon-water-filters/#:%7E:text=In%20water%20purification%2C%20activated%20carbon,component%20in%20many%20different%20industries) in the water and even improve taste.

As to why both at once, it is to foster the transient presence of active radical oxygen species (including H2O2, which will not introduce or interact with any organics present to possibly create any persistent problematic side products).

A comment on the chemistry without the application of electricity (just aeration), if iron is presence as Fe(HCO3)2, the action of oxygen could proceed as follows:

$\ce{ 2 Fe^{2+} (aq) + 3 O2 (d) + 6 H^{+} (aq) -> 2 Fe(OH)3 (s)}$

creating red insoluble ferric hydroxide (more commonly known as rust) through the action of aeration (or electrolysis) formed dissolved oxygen.

[EDIT] Relating to aerated electrolysis, [a patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4005014A/en) citing an application of caption gases from electrolysis that is further fed back into the system to effect a more prolonged and beneficial aeration effect. Also, a paper: [Aerated Electrolysis For Reducing Impacts of Shale Gas Production Wastewater on Water Sources regarding Disinfectant Byproducts Formation](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.estlett.8b00482) where the aeration process is of aid in reducing more problematic water contaminants that can be created via the electrolysis.